# PLS-00103 occurs in PL/SQL on Toad

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to PL/SQL procedure and tried to make one receiving some variables from Java.
I've faced PLS-00103 errors saying Encountered the symbol "SELECT" and ")" in SELECT statement between "is" and "begin" and Encountered the symbol "end-of-life" on the semi-colon after END
Please give me some clues about this errors and want to know why this happens.
Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SYS_APPL_TEMP_SAVE2 
(
  P_C_CD IN GEN3200.C_CD%TYPE
, P_APPL_ID IN GEN3200.APPL_ID%TYPE
, P_ITEM_CD IN GEN3200.ITEM_CD%TYPE
, P_SEQ_NO IN GEN3200.SEQ_NO%TYPE
, P_ITEM_SIZE_CD IN GEN3200.ITEM_SIZE_CD%TYPE
, P_APPL_CNT IN GEN3200.APPL_CNT%TYPE
, P_ORDER_YMD IN GEN3200.ORDER_YMD%TYPE
, P_OFFER_YMD IN GEN3200.OFFER_YMD%TYPE
, P_MOD_USER_ID IN GEN3200.MOD_USER_ID%TYPE
, P_MOD_YMDHMS IN GEN3200.MOD_YMDHMS%TYPE
)
IS

APPL_TYPE VARCHAR2(20) := 
(SELECT T1.APPL_TYPE 
  FROM SY7010 T1
     , GEN3200 T2
 WHERE T1.C_CD = T2.C_CD
   AND T2.C_CD = P_C_CD
   AND T1.APPL_ID = T2.APPL_ID
   AND T2.APPL_ID = P_APPL_ID);
   
   
EMP_ID VARCHAR2(20) :=
(SELECT T1.APPL_EMP_ID EMP_ID
  FROM SY7010 T1
     , GEN3200 T2
 WHERE T1.C_CD = T2.C_CD
   AND T2.C_CD = P_C_CD
   AND T1.APPL_ID = T2.APPL_ID
   AND T2.APPL_ID = P_APPL_ID);


BEGIN


SELECT CASE WHEN PERIOD_CD IS NULL THEN 'Y'
            WHEN (CK_CNT + P_APPL_CNT) <= LIMIT_CNT THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' END AS CK_YN
  FROM (
        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN T3.PERIOD_CD = '1' AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.APPL_YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') THEN T2.APPL_CNT
                    WHEN T3.PERIOD_CD = '2' AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.APPL_YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'MM') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') THEN T2.APPL_CNT 
                    WHEN T3.PERIOD_CD = '3' AND T1.APPL_YMD = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') THEN T2.APPL_CNT 
                    ELSE 0 END) AS CK_CNT
             , T3.PERIOD_CD
             , T3.LIMIT_CNT
          FROM SY7010 T1
             , GEN3200 T2
             , GEN3100 T3
         WHERE T1.C_CD = P_C_CD
           AND T1.APPL_TYPE = APPL_TYPE
           AND T1.TRG_EMP_ID = EMP_ID
           AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.APPL_YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
           AND T2.C_CD = T1.C_CD
           AND T2.APPL_ID = T1.APPL_ID
           AND T2.ITEM_CD = P_ITEM_CD
           AND T2.SEQ_NO = P_SEQ_NO
           AND T3.C_CD = T2.C_CD
           AND T3.ITEM_CD = T2.ITEM_CD
           AND T3.SEQ_NO = T2.SEQ_NO
         GROUP BY T3.PERIOD_CD, T3.LIMIT_CNT );


INSERT INTO GEN3200
(
C_CD
, APPL_ID
, ITEM_CD
, SEQ_NO
, ITEM_SIZE_CD
, APPL_CNT
, ORDER_YMD
, OFFER_YMD
, MOD_USER_ID
, MOD_YMDHMS
)
VALUES 
(
P_C_CD
, P_APPL_ID
, P_ITEM_CD
, P_SEQ_NO
, P_ITEM_SIZE_CD
, P_APPL_CNT
, P_ORDER_YMD
, P_OFFER_YMD
, P_MOD_USER_ID
, P_MOD_YMDHMS
);
COMMIT;


END P_SYS_APPL_TEMP_SAVE2;
/
```

- I have searched on google but cannot find the solution

Comment: you assign variable before the begin that is not allowed also look here for guidance how uit would look like https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your tables to test it, but:

- local variables declared in procedure's `DECLARE` section can't accept values as result of a `select` statement; you'll have to `select ... into` in procedure's executable section. See demo:

  ```
  SQL> declare
    2    l_val number := (select 1 from dual);
    3  begin
    4    null;
    5  end;
    6  /
    l_val number := (select 1 from dual);
                     *
  ERROR at line 2:
  ORA-06550: line 2, column 20:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
  ( - + case for mod new not null <an identifier>
  <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
  continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
  sum variance execute forall merge standard time timestamp
  interval date
  <a string literal with character set specification>
  <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
  <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>


  SQL> declare
    2    l_val number;
    3  begin
    4    select 1 into l_val from dual;
    5  end;
    6  /

  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
  ```
- the next `select` (that contains `case` expression) requires `into`; basically, all selects in PL/SQL require `into` clause (there are some exceptions, such as explicitly declared cursor, cursor `for` loop, subquery, ...)

  - it also means that you have to declare variable which will hold that value

This is your code, edited; see if it works. As I said, I can't run it without tables. If you still have problems, consider posting `CREATE TABLE` statements so that we could create environment which would let that procedure compile.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SYS_APPL_TEMP_SAVE2 
(
  P_C_CD IN GEN3200.C_CD%TYPE
, P_APPL_ID IN GEN3200.APPL_ID%TYPE
, P_ITEM_CD IN GEN3200.ITEM_CD%TYPE
, P_SEQ_NO IN GEN3200.SEQ_NO%TYPE
, P_ITEM_SIZE_CD IN GEN3200.ITEM_SIZE_CD%TYPE
, P_APPL_CNT IN GEN3200.APPL_CNT%TYPE
, P_ORDER_YMD IN GEN3200.ORDER_YMD%TYPE
, P_OFFER_YMD IN GEN3200.OFFER_YMD%TYPE
, P_MOD_USER_ID IN GEN3200.MOD_USER_ID%TYPE
, P_MOD_YMDHMS IN GEN3200.MOD_YMDHMS%TYPE
)
IS
  APPL_TYPE VARCHAR2(20);
  EMP_ID VARCHAR2(20);
  l_yn varchar2(1);
BEGIN
SELECT T1.APPL_TYPE into appl_type
  FROM SY7010 T1
     , GEN3200 T2
 WHERE T1.C_CD = T2.C_CD
   AND T2.C_CD = P_C_CD
   AND T1.APPL_ID = T2.APPL_ID
   AND T2.APPL_ID = P_APPL_ID;
      
SELECT T1.APPL_EMP_ID into emp_id
  FROM SY7010 T1
     , GEN3200 T2
 WHERE T1.C_CD = T2.C_CD
   AND T2.C_CD = P_C_CD
   AND T1.APPL_ID = T2.APPL_ID
   AND T2.APPL_ID = P_APPL_ID;

SELECT CASE WHEN PERIOD_CD IS NULL THEN 'Y'
            WHEN (CK_CNT + P_APPL_CNT) <= LIMIT_CNT THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' END AS CK_YN
  INTO l_yn
  FROM (
        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN T3.PERIOD_CD = '1' AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.APPL_YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') THEN T2.APPL_CNT
                    WHEN T3.PERIOD_CD = '2' AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.APPL_YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'MM') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') THEN T2.APPL_CNT 
                    WHEN T3.PERIOD_CD = '3' AND T1.APPL_YMD = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') THEN T2.APPL_CNT 
                    ELSE 0 END) AS CK_CNT
             , T3.PERIOD_CD
             , T3.LIMIT_CNT
          FROM SY7010 T1
             , GEN3200 T2
             , GEN3100 T3
         WHERE T1.C_CD = P_C_CD
           AND T1.APPL_TYPE = APPL_TYPE
           AND T1.TRG_EMP_ID = EMP_ID
           AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.APPL_YMD, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
           AND T2.C_CD = T1.C_CD
           AND T2.APPL_ID = T1.APPL_ID
           AND T2.ITEM_CD = P_ITEM_CD
           AND T2.SEQ_NO = P_SEQ_NO
           AND T3.C_CD = T2.C_CD
           AND T3.ITEM_CD = T2.ITEM_CD
           AND T3.SEQ_NO = T2.SEQ_NO
         GROUP BY T3.PERIOD_CD, T3.LIMIT_CNT );

INSERT INTO GEN3200
(
C_CD
, APPL_ID
, ITEM_CD
, SEQ_NO
, ITEM_SIZE_CD
, APPL_CNT
, ORDER_YMD
, OFFER_YMD
, MOD_USER_ID
, MOD_YMDHMS
)
VALUES 
(
P_C_CD
, P_APPL_ID
, P_ITEM_CD
, P_SEQ_NO
, P_ITEM_SIZE_CD
, P_APPL_CNT
, P_ORDER_YMD
, P_OFFER_YMD
, P_MOD_USER_ID
, P_MOD_YMDHMS
);
COMMIT;
END P_SYS_APPL_TEMP_SAVE2;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the issue is related to the subqueries you have in your code. In PL/SQL, if you want to use a subquery to assign a value to a variable, you should enclose the subquery within parentheses.

For example, instead of:

```
APPL_TYPE VARCHAR2(20) :=
SELECT T1.APPL_TYPE 
  FROM SY7010 T1
     , GEN3200 T2
 WHERE T1.C_CD = T2.C_CD
   AND T2.C_CD = P_C_CD
   AND T1.APPL_ID = T2.APPL_ID
   AND T2.APPL_ID = P_APPL_ID;
```

You should use:

```
APPL_TYPE VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT T1.APPL_TYPE 
  INTO APPL_TYPE
  FROM SY7010 T1
     , GEN3200 T2
 WHERE T1.C_CD = T2.C_CD
   AND T2.C_CD = P_C_CD
   AND T1.APPL_ID = T2.APPL_ID
   AND T2.APPL_ID = P_APPL_ID;
END;
```